# Site statistics

Tags: discussion, beta, statistics

Following on from the great work of [F'x](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2700/fx) over on [Academia.SE](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/q/283/96), this meta post will track [our stats on Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/33364/sustainable-living), **fortnightly** (previously weekly) or a bit longer if I forget and someone else updates it.

**You can help build the site**, by asking questions, answering questions, and by sharing links to particular questions and answers across social media: use the "share" link on posts to generate a URL that can earn you [bronze](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/badges/59/announcer), [silver](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/badges/60/booster) and [gold](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/badges/61/publicist) badges.

| 2021 | Day in beta | Q's/day | Answered | Rep 200+ | 2K+ | 3K+ | Tot.Users | A.ratio | Visit/day |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| May-25 | 3037 | 0.5 | 95% | 355 | 21 | 13 | 8020 | 2.1 | 684 |
| May-03 | 3015 | 0.4 | 95% | 354 | 21 | 13 | 7944 | 2.1 | 798 |
| Apr-14 | 2996 | 0.1 | 95% | 353 | 21 | 13 | 7866 | 2.1 | 765 |
| Apr-01 | 2983 | 0.5 | 95% | 353 | 21 | 13 | 7796 | 2.1 | 801 |
| Mar-17 | 2968 | 0.6 | 95% | 353 | 21 | 13 | 7737 | 2.1 | 780 |
| Mar-03 | 2954 | 0.4 | 95% | 353 | 21 | 13 | 7694 | 2.1 | 859 |
| Feb-10 | 2933 | 0.6 | 95% | 358 | 21 | 13 | 7641 | 2.1 | 860 |
| Jan-27 | 2919 | 0.2 | 95% | 352 | 21 | 13 | 7598 | 2.1 | 863 |
| Jan-06 | 2898 | 0.4 | 94% | 350 | 21 | 13 | 7517 | 2.1 | 862 |

```
2020  days in  Q's  A'd   ______Users_______    A   Visits
        beta    /d        200+ 2k+ 3k+ Total  ratio   /d
____________________________________________________________
Dec-16  2877   0.4  94%   348  21  13   7473   2.1    784
Nov-25  2856   0.1  93%   347  21  13   7423   2.1    773
Nov-11  2842   0.6  93%   346  21  13   7394   2.1    777
Oct-30  2830   0.5  93%   346  21  13   7378   2.1    856
Oct-08  2808   0.9  93%   345  21  13   7323   2.1    779
Sep-11  2781   1.7  94%   345  21  13   7250   2.1    742 
Aug-28  2767   0.5  94%   342  21  13   7250   2.1    729
Aug-28  2767   0.5  94%   342  21  13   7250   2.1    729
Aug-16  2755   0.5  94%   342  21  13   7222   2.1    721
Jul-29  2737   0.5  95%   342  21  13   7191   2.1    737
Jul-15  2723   0.3  95%   342  21  13   7159   2.1    757
Jul-01  2709   0.4  95%   340  21  13   7128   2.1    801
Jun-17  2695   0.4  95%   340  21  13   7100   2.1    825
Jun-03  2681   0.1  95%   340  21  13   7074   2.1    936
May-20  2667   0.3  95%   340  21  13   7046   2.1    973
May-06  2653   0.4  95%   340  21  13   7014   2.1   1230
Apr-24  2641   0.6  95%   341  21  13   6986   2.1   1243
Apr-08  2625   0.6  95%   341  21  13   6945   2.1   1030
Mar-26  2612   0.5  95%   340  21  13   6923   2.1   1011
Mar-11  2597   0.7  96%   340  21  13   6902   2.1   1061
Feb-26  2583   0.8  95%   336  21  12   6848   2.1   1100
Feb-12  2569   0.5  96%   334  21  12   6798   2.1   1110
Jan-22  2548   0.4  96%   332  21  12   6710   2.1   1240
Jan-08  2534   0.7  95%   330  21  12   6664   2.1   1106

The quantcast widget was not updated anymore since Jan 27 2020 so no statistics were gathered


2019  days in  Q's  A'd   ______Users_______    A   Visits Quantcast
        beta    /d        200+ 2k+ 3k+ Total  ratio   /d      /m
____________________________________________________________________
Dec-23  2518   0.5  96%   327  21  12   6599   2.1   1056    28 596
Dec-04  2485   1.1  95%   325  21  12   6559   2.1   1091    34 448
Nov-20  2485   1.2  95%   324  21  12** 6534   2.1   1388    38 571
Nov-06  2471   0.6  95%   229  19   9   6480   2.1   1459    39 686
Oct-24  2457   0.6  95%   229  19   9   6449   2.1   1520    39 238
Oct-10  2443   0.9  95%   229  19   9   6409   2.1   1446    36 808
Sep-25  2429   0.9  95%   228  19   9   6359   2.1   1330    35 000
Sep-11  2415   0.8  96%   227  19   9   6306   2.1   1298    36 482
Aug-28  2401   0.6  96%   226  19   9   6274   2.1   1340    36 253
Aug-14  2387   0.3  96%   226  19   9   6222   2.1   1302    35 785
Jul-31  2373   0.6  96%   226  19   9   6196   2.1   1372    37 203
Jul-17  2359   0.5  96%   225  19   9   6160   2.1   1386    38 060
Jul-03  2331   0.4  96%   224  19   9   6121   2.1   1463    39 061
Jun-19  2331   0.4  96%   224  19   9   6083   2.1   1463    38 516
Jun-05  2317   0.7  96%   223  18   9   6039   2.1   1392    39 800
May-22  2303   n/a* n/a*  225  18   9   n/a*   n/a*  n/a*    42 612
May-15  2296   0.9  96%   224  18   9   5985   2.1   1531    42 143
Apr-24  2275   0.6  96%   222  18   9   5939   2.1   1408    40 272
Apr-10  2261   0.6  96%   221  18   9   5896   2.1   1435    41 245
Mar-27  2247   0.6  96%   221  18   9   5858   2.1   1472    44 616
Mar-20  2240   0.4  96%   221  18   9   5840   2.1   1577    45 554
Feb-27  2219   0.6  96%   218  18   9   5795   2.1   1629    47 286
Feb-13  2205   0.2  96%   218  18   9   5760   2.1   1632    49 177
Jan-30  2191   0.2  96%   217  17   9   5721   2.1   1737    48 063
Jan-16  2177   0.7  96%   217  17   9   5689   2.1   1739    42 857
Jan-02  2163   0.4  96%   216  16   9   5652   2.1   1431    41 238

 * Statistics not available due to a bug 
  (see https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/328802/164138)
** Retroactive reputation changes due to changed question upvote weight 
  (see https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/11/13/were-rewarding-the-question-askers/) 


2018  days in  Q's  A'd   ______Users_______    A   Visits Quantcast
        beta    /d        200+ 2k+ 3k+ Total  ratio   /d      /m
____________________________________________________________________

Dec-19  2149   1.1  96%   215  16   9   5631   2.1   1627    47 062
Dec-05  2135   0.6  96%   214  16   9   5589   2.1   1704    46 999
Nov-21  2121   0.4  96%   214  16   9   5550   2.1   1660    44 077
Nov-07  2107   0.3  96%   212  16   9   5514   2.1   1554    43 643
Oct-24  2093   0.8  95%   210  16   9   5486   2.1   1596    41 749
Oct-10  2079   0.9  96%   210  16   9   5442   2.1   1431    38 445
Sep-26  2065   0.6  95%   208  16   9   5415   2.1   1380    37 284
Sep-12  2051   0.1  96%   207  16   9   5382   2.1   1399    38 102
Aug-29  2037   0.7  95%   207  16   9   5359   2.1   1399    38 024
Aug-15  2023   0.3  95%   206  16   9   5325   2.1   1460    35 611
Aug-01  2009   0.6  95%   206  16   9   5295   2.1   1211    33 025
Jul-18  1995   0.1  96%   206  16   9   5263   2.1   1265    33 571
Jul-04  1981   0.9  96%   205  16   9   5239   2.1   1276    34 551
Jun-20  1967   0.4  96%   206  16   9   5204   2.1   n/a**   34 895
Jun-06  1953   0.6  95%   204  16   9   5172   2.1   n/a**   35 303
May-23  1939   0.5  95%   204  16   8   5136   2.1   n/a**   36 651
May-09  1925   1.0  95%   203  16   8   5097   2.1   n/a**   42 272
Apr-25  1911   0.8  95%   202  16   8   5060   2.1   n/a**   42 303
Apr-11  1897   0.9  96%   201  16   8   5024   2.1   1473    41 308
Mar-28  1883   0.8  95%   200  16   8   4976   2.1   1556    40 813
Mar-14  1869   0.7  96%   200  16   7   4930   2.1   1593    39 938
Feb-28  1855   0.8  96%   198  16   7   4892   2.1   1375    39 258
Feb-14  1841   0.5  96%   198  16   7   4848   2.1   1481    41 381
Jan-31  1827   0.6  96%   198  16   7   4794*  2.1   1579    46 789
Jan-17  1813   0.6  96%   198  16   7   4842   2.1   1735    44 557
Jan-04  1800   0.4  96%   198  16   7   4800   2.1   1647    41 175

*  Decline in total users is caused by deletion of 107 spam accounts 
   (see https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/306180/)
** Because of a bug the visits/day statistic was temporarily not available 
   (see https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/308966/164138) 


2017  days in  Q's  A'd   ______Users_______    A   Visits Quantcast
        beta    /d        200+ 2k+ 3k+ Total  ratio   /d      /m
____________________________________________________________________

Dec-21  1786   0.8  96%   197  16   7   4770   2.1   1516    40 443
Dec-06  1771   0.4  96%   197  16   7   4725   2.1   1558    42 186
Nov-22  1757   0.4  97%   197  16   7   4588   2.1   1636    42 602
Nov-08  1743   0.5  97%   197  16   6   4539   2.1   1623    39 620
Oct-25  1729   0.4  96%   195  16   6   4506   2.1   1474    36 631
Oct-11  1715   0.3  97%   194  16   6   4473   2.1   1338    39 075
Sep-27  1701   0.2  96%   193  16   6   4441   2.1   1474    41 994
Sep-13  1687   0.4  96%   191  15   6   4409   2.1   1574    39 324
Aug-30  1673   0.4  96%   191  15   6   4388   2.1   1435    36 840
Aug-16  1659   0.6  96%   190  15   6   4356   2.1   1374    36 627
Aug-02  1645   0.1  96%   190  15   6   4327   2.1   1355    37 489
Jul-19  1631   0.6  96%   190  15   6   4281   2.1   1415    38 458
Jul-05  1617   0.4  96%   189  15   6   4239   2.1   1410    39 057
Jun-21  1603   0.5  96%   189  15   6   4186   2.1   1415    39 868
Jun-07  1589   0.4  97%   188  14   6   4155   2.1   1504    39 867
May-24  1575   0.4  97%   188  14   6   4113   2.1   1496    39 758
May-10  1561   0.4  97%   188  14   6   4069   2.1   1546    40 420
Apr-26  1547   0.4  97%   188  13   6   4027   2.1   1579    40 690
Apr-12  1533   0.4  97%   188  13   6   4006   2.1   1562    39 428
Mar-29  1519   0.6  97%   188  13   6   3979   2.1   1467    39 013
Mar-15  1505   0.6  97%   188  13   6   3936   2.1   1511    38 962
Mar-02  1492   0.9  97%   187  13   6   3901   2.1   1444    39 680
Feb-15  1477   0.6  97%   187  13   6   3861   2.1   1493    42 170
Feb-01  1463   0.5  97%   186  13   6   3819   2.1   1673    47 682
Jan-18  1449   0.6  97%   186  13   6   3778   2.1   1822    45 622
Jan-05  1421   0.9  95%   183  13   6   3712   2.1   1878    49 758


2016  days in  Q's  A'd   ______Users_______    A   Visits Quantcast
        beta    /d        200+ 2k+ 3k+ Total  ratio   /d      /m
____________________________________________________________________

Dec-21  1436   0.5  96%   183  13   6   3750   2.1   1411    44 442
Dec-08  1408   0.9  95%   183  13   6   3665   2.1   1862    45 248
Nov-23  1393   0.8  94%   181  13   6   3621   2.1   1535    40 467
Nov-09  1379   0.8  94%   181  13   6   3559   2.1   1451    37 761
Oct-26  1365   0.3  95%   180  12   6   3559   2.1   1405    35 679
Oct-12  1351   0.4  95%   180  12   6   3515   2.1   1275    33 379
Sep-28  1337   0.6  95%   179  12   6   3465   2.1   1229    31 653
Sep-15  1324   0.4  95%   179  12   6   3438   2.1   1213    30 955
Sep-08  1317   0.6  95%   179  12   6   3419   2.1   1183    30 068
Aug-17  1295   0.6  95%   174  12   6   3355   2.1   1094    29 181
Aug-03  1281   0.9  95%   174  12   6   3325   2.1   1075    29 549
Jul-20  1267   0.6  95%   173  12   6   3285   2.1   1125    29 616
Jul-06  1253   0.9  95%   171  12   6   3242   2.1   1093    29 315
Jun-22  1239   0.8  96%   170  12   6   3216   2.1   1055    29 771
Jun-08  1225   0.8  96%   169  12   6   3175   2.1   1154    31 354
May-25  1211   0.6  96%   169  12   6   3134   2.1   1216    32 260
May-11  1197   0.5  96%   169  12   6   3104   2.1   1212    33 329
Apr-28  1183   0.7  96%   168  12   6   3065   2.1   1288    33 610
Apr-14  1169   1.0  96%   168  12   6   3018   2.1   1208    31 219
Mar-30  1155   0.5  96%   166  12   6   2968   2.1   1070    29 055
Mar-16  1141   0.5  96%   166  11   6   2914   2.1   1136    30 346
Mar-02  1127   0.4  96%   166  11   6   2868   2.1   1142    31 463
Feb-17  1113   0.6  96%   165  11   6   2827   2.1   1177    35 540
Feb-03  1099   0.9  96%   164  11   6   2791   2.1   1237    39 008
Jan-20  1085   0.4  96%   162  11   6   2737   2.1   1458    36 259
Jan-06  1071   0.7  96%   160  11   6   2695   2.1   1291    32 763


2015  days in  Q's  A'd   ______Users_______    A   Visits Quantcast
        beta    /d        200+ 2k+ 3k+ Total  ratio   /d      /m
____________________________________________________________________

Dec-24  1043   1.2  95%   160  11   6   2661   2.1   1152    34 650
Dec-09  1043   0.7  95%   155  11   6   2623   2.1   1294    36 693
Nov-25  1029   0.9  95%   153  10   6   2576   2.1   1390    37 127
Nov-18  1022   0.7  95%   153  10   6   2562   2.1   1399    36 955
Oct-28  1001   0.5  95%   152  10   6   2506   2.1   1350    36 219
Oct-14   987   0.4  96%   151  10   6   2469   2.1   1289    32 671
Sep-30   973   0.5  96%   150  10   6   2424   2.1   1129    29 839
Sep-16   959   0.6  96%   149  10   6   2389   2.1   1055    28 039
Sep-02   945   0.3  96%   148  10   6   2360   2.1   1006    27 411
Aug-19   931   0.9  96%   147  10   6   2329   2.1    979    26 842
Aug-05   917   0.6  96%   147  10   6   2270   2.1    951    25 791
Jul-22   903   0.9  96%   147  10   6   2228   2.1    967    25 586
Jul-08   889   0.4  97%   147  10   6   2203   2.1    947    26 005
Jun-24   875   0.4  97%   147   9   5   2180   2.1   1003    27 173
Jun-11   862   0.6  97%   147   9   5   2139   2.1    994    27 291
May-28   848   0.6  97%   147   9   5   2108   2.1   1031    26 504
May-17   837   0.4  97%   147   9   5   2095   2.1    981    26 399
Apr-29   819   0.7  97%   145   9   5   2055   2.1    976    25 252
Apr-15   805   0.4  97%   144   9   5   2021   2.1    880    23 586
Apr-03   793   0.4  97%   142   9   5   2007   2.1    851    23 197
Mar-18   777   0.7  97%   142   9   5   1969   2.1    868    27 197
Mar-04   763   0.4  97%   142   8   5   1950   2.1   1024    28 474
Feb-18   749   0.5  97%   142   8   5   1915   2.1    927    27 129
Feb-04   735   0.9  97%   140   8   5   1882   2.1    987    30 323
Jan-22   722   0.6  98%   140   8   5   1854   2.1   1063    29 438
Jan-07   707   0.6  98%   140   8   5   1820   2.1   1091    25 317


2014  days in  Q's  A'd   ______Users_______    A   Visits Quantcast
        beta    /d        200+ 2k+ 3k+ Total  ratio   /d      /m
____________________________________________________________________

Dec-24   694   0.6  97%   140   8   5   1791   2.1    854    25 038
Dec-11   680   0.7  97%   140   8   5   1757   2.1    932    29 401
Nov-25   664   0.8  97%   139   8   5   1725   2.1   1231    28 128
Nov-12   651   0.4  97%   137   8   5   1702   2.1    932    22 910
Oct-29   637   0.2  97%   135   7   5   1669   2.1    806    20 789
Oct-15   624   0.9  97%   134   7   5   1652   2.1    805    17 668
Oct-01   610   0.5  97%   134   7   5   1619   2.1    531    13 125

___/ Google Panda 4.1 update upgrades Google rankings \_____________

Sep-17   595   0.9  96%   130   7   5   1599   2.1    427    10 936
Sep-04   582   0.6  97%   127   7   5   1588   2.1    396    10 330
Aug-20   567   0.7  97%   124   7   5   1556   2.1    382    10 467
Aug-06   553   0.3  97%   124   7   5   1530   2.1    406    10 891
Jul-23   539   0.5  97%   123   7   5   1500   2.1    409    11 056
Jul-09   525   0.3  97%   122   7   5   1474   2.1    401    10 787
Jun-25   511   0.7  96%   120   7   5   1442   2.1    401    10 645
Jun-11   497   0.5  97%   119   7   5   1418   2.1    447    15 032
May-28   483   0.4  97%   116   7   5   1402   2.1    537    20 854

___/ Google Panda 4.0 update downgrades Google rankings \___________

May-14   469   0.5  97%   115   7   5   1367   2.1    888    22 583
Apr-30   455   0.5  97%   113   7   5   1340   2.0    818    20 709
Apr-16   441   0.6  97%   112   7   5   1298   2.0    776    21 885
Apr-02   427   0.7  97%   111   7   5   1255   2.0    874    22 838
Mar-19   413   1.0  98%   114   7   4   1209   2.0    834    22 464
Mar-05   399   0.6  97%   110   7   2   1180   2.0    849    23 652
Feb-19   385   1.1  97%   109   7   2   1143   2.0    874    25 482
Feb-05   371   0.6  97%   106   7   2   1094   2.0   1025    27 073

___/ Now we are one. Congratulations on our first anniversary \_____

Jan-30   1 y   0.6  97%   105   7   2   1077   2.0   1018    27 368
Jan-22   357   0.5  97%   104   7   2   1052   2.0    789    23 702
Jan-08   343   0.6  97%   102   7   2   1006   2.0    761    22 422


2013  days in  Q's  A'd   ______Users_______    A   Visits Quantcast
        beta    /d        200+ 2k+ 3k+ Total  ratio   /d      /m
____________________________________________________________________

Dec-25   329   0.3  97%   101   7   2    965   2.0    671    23 076
Dec-11   315   0.4  97%   100   7   2    926   2.0    856    23 611
Nov-27   301   0.4  96%    99   7   2    890   2.0    756    19 667
Nov-13   287   0.7  96%    97   7   2    857   2.0    666    15 762
Oct-30   273   0.4  95%    92   7   2    833   2.0    481    12 854
Oct-16   259   0.5  95%    91   7   2    809   1.9    431    11 136
Oct-02   245   0.4  96%    88   7   2    788   1.9    363     9 597
Sep-18   231   0.4  94%    88   7   2    757   1.9    316     8 014
Sep-04   217   0.4  94%    88   7   2    733   2.0    260     7 630

___/ Quantcast changed their algorithm here \_______________________

Aug-21   203   0.3  95%    88   7   2    716   1.9    281     5 710
Aug-07   189   0.4  94%    86   7   2    689   1.9    257     5 183
Jul-24   175   0.6  94%    86   7   2    675   1.9    246     4 994
Jul-10   161   0.7  95%    85   6   2    646   1.9    215     4 754

___/ switched from weekly to fortnightly here \_____________________

Jun-26   147   0.6  94%    85   5   2    624   1.9    221     4 400
Jun-19   140   1.0  95%    85   5   1    612   1.9    201     4 172
Jun-12   133   1.7  95%    84   2   1    599   1.8    198     4 132
Jun-05   126   1.4  96%    83   2   1    580   1.9    212     4 046
May-29   119   1.2  96%    82   2   1    568   1.9    196     3 629
May-22   112   0.9  95%    81   2   1    552   1.9    179     3 079
May-15   105   1.3  95%    81   2   1    536   1.9    154     2 683
May-08    98   2.0  95%    79   2   1    526   1.9    107     2 344
May-01    91   1.6  95%    72   2   1    505   1.9     99     2 377
Apr-24    84   1.1  96%    75   2   0    486   1.8     93     2 426
Apr-17    77   1.4  96%    72   2   0    466   1.8    100     2 633
Apr-08    68   1.1  96%    58   2   0    441   1.8    106     2 492
Apr-03    63   1.1  96%    57   1   0    423   1.8    106     2 142
Mar-27    56   1.4  95%    56   1   0    403   1.8     92
Mar-20    49   1.3  95%    52   1   0    376   1.8     60
Mar-13    42   1.4  95%    49   0   0    341   1.8     47
Mar-06    35   2.0  92%    48   0   0    315   1.8     46
Feb-27    28   2.6  94%    46   0   0    296   1.8     56
Feb-20    21   4.1  93%    42   0   0    268   1.7     65
Feb-13    14   8.9  93%    41   0   0    236   1.7    113
Feb-06     7  16.6  89%    34   0   0    187   1.6    120
```

Moderators have a view of the site's statistics, but they cannot share the specifics. So, I'm starting this post to keep track of the evolution of our publicly available statistics over time. Please feel free to update it every now and then.

I use the [Area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/33364/sustainable-living) page as source for those stats, in addition to the Quantcast figure.

Questions/day is a rolling 2-week mean. Visits/day is a rolling two-week median.

See also [this answer on the mother meta which contains a list of links to similar stats-tracking posts on other beta sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/230949/164022)

Comment: Great to see that just before our birthday we got more than 1000 users and over 1000 visits/day. If we now just can get that question/day ratio up, then we are are well on our way to graduate and lose our beta status.

Comment: [Users with 5000+ rep](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/site-analytics) can also check out some statistics graphs [here](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/site-analytics)

Answer (score 12):

The enthusiasm here is awesome. Just a note, make sure you don't [look at those stats too often](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161266/how-long-will-betas-be-given-to-develop-a-following/161294#161294). If you can't resist - try not to get overly concerned if you don't see them moving very much over time. The stats are there so the community has a *general* idea of how the site is growing, but little to no movement for protracted amounts of time is common in this phase and observing that in close repetition can sap your motivation.

I check on the site daily, and each week I do a pretty thorough examination of all metrics that are available to me. If I see a cause for concern, I'll definitely raise it here for discussion. Again, I think it's great that you're tracking it, I just want to make sure that everyone knows - if we see problems, we'll raise discussions, so don't spend *too* much time worrying if you see slow / no / backwards growth.

Comment: Welcome, Tim. Nice to have you here. *hits F5 repeatedly to see if this answer has updated*

Answer (score 10):

for what it is worth, I am enjoying this site for several reasons, one reason in particular is the collegiality.

When a question is asked, it is often well thought out, insightful and makes people think.  This leads to often multiple answers, where information that is insightful, well researched is presented in a well thought out manner.

It is a truly professional site.

Answer (score 3):

I was curious about the trends in this data, so I put a few simple charts together:

[image: Visits per day]
[image: Questions and answers]
[image: Users]

---

- Note 2019-12-04: I adjusted the scale on the Q/A chart so you can't tell what happened the first four weeks of the site, but it's easier to see the long term trends.
- Note 2020-07-16: Since Quantcast is no longer provided, I switched to the daily visits data.

Comment: Thanks for doing this!