# Biweekly Topic Challenge - suggest a topic now!

Tags: discussion, challenge

Jon Ericson has come up with [a wonderful way](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/240634/how-do-weekly-topic-challenges-work) to boost the amount of questions on the site, and promote activity in topics that may otherwise receive only minimal attention. And it will be a lot of fun. Here's how it works:

1. Suggest topics in the answers below.
2. Next week, I (or a volunteer) will pick one of the topics and write up a new meta post introducing the challenge for the following challenge. The topic will be associated with a specific tag (or tag set) so that we can count how many questions were asked. Please use one topic per answer.
3. Anyone who wants to participate asks about the topic of the period.
4. At the end of the period, the organizer post an answer to the challenge with a count of how many questions were asked and anything else they feel like highlighting (like favorite questions or notable achievements).
5. The organizer picks a new topic and starts back on step #2.

Note: It's fine to ask a question you know the answer to, and posting your own question/answer is good. I'll probably do this, but post my question before my answer by a day or so, to get more input.

You can add topics to this list at any time, and if(when) we run out, this challenge series ends. Feedback? Comment below this post, or find me in [our chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7310/sustainable-living). Have fun, folks!

Answer (score 2):

Very interesting idea! I was thinking about starting some sort of contest just last week, but hadn't figured out in what form. My idea was to try and see if we somehow can improve the number of questions on sustainability on a macro level, because we still have only few of those. As was discussed in [this meta post](https://sustainability.meta.stackexchange.com/q/186/99) we would like to show that those type of questions are also on-topic here.

I guess macro-sustainability is too broad for a biweekly challenge, but I'll narrow it down and suggest **world population growth**.

Comment: Can you think of a tag/tag set to use for questions in this challenge? It will help a lot when we tally up the final results.

Comment: I think we'd need to create a new tag for this; [population] or alternatively [world-population].

Answer (score 2):

[electricity](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/electricity) from [renewables](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/renewables)

Answer (score 1):

How about the tag set [animals](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/animals) and [husbandry](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/husbandry)? Those are fun topics, at least for me, and I may be able to ask a few myself.

Answer (score 1):

[industrial-production](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/industrial-production) - steel, cement, plastics, that sort of thing. Hard processes to decarbonise

Answer (score 1):

[cars](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cars) and other [transport](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/transport)