# Biweekly Topic Challenge: ask about population! [completed]

Tags: discussion, challenge

I made a [post](https://sustainability.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/211/biweekly-topic-challenge-suggest-a-topic-now) asking for topic ideas for the challenge, and the [highest suggestion](https://sustainability.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/211/biweekly-topic-challenge-suggest-a-topic-now/212#212) is for [population](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/population).

This tag must be created for the first question, as it currently does not exist. Use/create other appropriate tags as necessary if they are relevant to your question.

Please use the tag [population](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/population) when posting questions for this challenge, and remember to keep the site quality at a good level.

In two weeks, on December 1, I will tally up the results to see how we did, in an answer below this post. Feedback? Comment below this post or find me in [our chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7310/sustainable-living). Have fun!

Comment: I've created [the first question](http://sustainability.stackexchange.com/q/3138/99) and decided to go with the slightly broader tag [population], instead of [world-population]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

During the week that the challenge ran, we received 2 questions tagged [population](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/population):

- [How much is the world population expected to grow in the next decades?](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/3138/how-much-is-the-world-population-expected-to-grow-in-the-next-decades)
- [What is the IPAT identity, and does it still matter?](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/3142/what-is-the-ipat-identity-and-does-it-still-matter)

These questions have attracted 2 answers. Here are the participants:

**Askers:**

[image: profile for thelper at Sustainable Living Stack Exchange, Q&A for folks dedicated to a lifestyle that can be maintained indefinitely without depleting available resources]

[image: profile for energynumbers at Sustainable Living Stack Exchange, Q&A for folks dedicated to a lifestyle that can be maintained indefinitely without depleting available resources]

**Answerers:**

[image: profile for thelper at Sustainable Living Stack Exchange, Q&A for folks dedicated to a lifestyle that can be maintained indefinitely without depleting available resources]