# Biweekly Topic Challenge: ask about animals/husbandry! [completed]

Tags: discussion, challenge

I made a [post](https://sustainability.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/211/biweekly-topic-challenge-suggest-a-topic-now) asking for topic ideas for the challenge, and the [highest suggestion](https://sustainability.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/211/biweekly-topic-challenge-suggest-a-topic-now/213#213) is for [animals](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/animals) and [husbandry](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/husbandry).

Please use the tag [animals](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/animals) and [husbandry](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/husbandry) when posting questions for this challenge, and remember to keep the site quality at a good level.

In two weeks, on December 15, I will tally up the results to see how we did, in an answer below this post. Feedback? Comment below this post or find me in [our chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7310/sustainable-living). Have fun!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This challenge did not bring any results.