# Biweekly Topic Challenge: ask about electricity from renewables! [completed]

Tags: discussion, challenge

I made a [post](https://sustainability.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/211/biweekly-topic-challenge-suggest-a-topic-now) asking for topic ideas for the challenge, and the [highest suggestion](https://sustainability.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/211/biweekly-topic-challenge-suggest-a-topic-now/214#214) is for [electricity](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/electricity) from [renewables](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/renewables).

Please use the tags [electricity](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/electricity) and [renewables](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/renewables) when posting questions for this challenge, and remember to keep the site quality at a good level.

In two weeks, on December 29, I will tally up the results to see how we did, in an answer below this post. Feedback? Comment below this post or find me in [our chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7310/sustainable-living). Have fun!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During the week that the challenge ran, we received 3 questions tagged [electricity](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/electricity) and [renewables](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/renewables):

- [What are the physical limits on wind turbine size?](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/3207/what-are-the-physical-limits-on-wind-turbine-size)
- [What scope is there for price reductions in photovoltaic inverter costs?](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/3208/what-scope-is-there-for-price-reductions-in-photovoltaic-inverter-costs)
- [Where are the world's wave resources, beyond the UK and Portugal?](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/3212/where-are-the-worlds-wave-resources-beyond-the-uk-and-portugal)

These questions have attracted 2 answers. Here are the participants:

**Askers:**

[image: profile for energynumbers at Sustainable Living Stack Exchange, Q&A for folks dedicated to a lifestyle that can be maintained indefinitely without depleting available resources]

**Answerers:**

[image: profile for sherwood-botsford at Sustainable Living Stack Exchange, Q&A for folks dedicated to a lifestyle that can be maintained indefinitely without depleting available resources]

[image: profile for simon-w at Sustainable Living Stack Exchange, Q&A for folks dedicated to a lifestyle that can be maintained indefinitely without depleting available resources]