# Biweekly Topic Challenge: ask about industrial-production! [completed]

Tags: discussion, challenge

I made a [post](https://sustainability.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/211/biweekly-topic-challenge-suggest-a-topic-now) asking for topic ideas for the challenge, and the [highest suggestion](https://sustainability.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/211/biweekly-topic-challenge-suggest-a-topic-now/214#214) is for [industrial-production](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/industrial-production).

Please use the tags [industrial-production](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/industrial-production) when posting questions for this challenge, and remember to keep the site quality at a good level.

In two weeks, I will tally up the results to see how we did, in an answer below this post. Feedback? Comment below this post or find me in [our chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7310/sustainable-living). Have fun!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

During the week that the challenge ran, we received 3 questions tagged [industrial-production](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/industrial-production):

- [Most promising decarbonisation routes for clinker, cement and concrete?](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/4269/most-promising-decarbonisation-routes-for-clinker-cement-and-concrete)
- [Best options for decarbonising steel production?](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/4270/best-options-for-decarbonising-steel-production)
- [Optimising crop yields without using fossil-fuel-manufactured fertiliser](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/4271/optimising-crop-yields-without-using-fossil-fuel-manufactured-fertiliser)

These questions have attracted 1 answer. Here are the participants:

**Askers:**

[image: profile for energynumbers at Sustainable Living Stack Exchange, Q&A for folks dedicated to a lifestyle that can be maintained indefinitely without depleting available resources]

**Answerers:**

[image: profile for freedom at Sustainable Living Stack Exchange, Q&A for folks dedicated to a lifestyle that can be maintained indefinitely without depleting available resources]