# Biweekly Topic Challenge: ask about cars and other transport!

Tags: discussion, challenge

I made a [post](https://sustainability.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/211/biweekly-topic-challenge-suggest-a-topic-now) asking for topic ideas for the challenge, and the [highest suggestion](https://sustainability.meta.stackexchange.com/a/216/1495) is for [cars](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cars) and other [transport](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/transport).

Please use the tags [cars](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cars) and/or [transport](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/transport) when posting questions for this challenge, and remember to keep the site quality at a good level.

In two weeks, I will tally up the results to see how we did, in an answer below this post. Feedback? Comment below this post or find me in [our chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7310/sustainable-living). Have fun!