# update the site description

Tags: discussion, status-completed, site-promotion

At the top of the [site tour](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/tour), it currently says:

> Sustainable Living Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for folks dedicated to a lifestyle that can be maintained indefinitely without depleting available resources. It's built and run *by you* as part of the Stack Exchange network of Q&A sites. With your help, we're working together to build a library of detailed answers to every question about sustainable living.

What do you think? Any suggestions for improvements.

They typically follow quite a specific recipe:

> **{site name}** is a question and answer site for {the site's primary audience}. It's built and run *by you* as part of the Stack Exchange network of Q&A sites. With your help, we're working together to build a library of detailed answers to every question about {site subject}.

Comment: Good point! I'd really like to see the current description changed into something more accurate

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> **Sustainable Living Stack Exchange** is a question and answer site for people trying to live a sustainable lifestyle, for professionals in renewable energy and other clean technology, and – most importantly – for you. It's built and run *by you* as part of the Stack Exchange network of Q&A sites. With your help, we're working together to build a library of detailed answers to every question on sustainability issues including climate change, renewable energy and sustainable resources.

Comment: I think this is perfect now.

Comment: Implemented today

Answer (score 2):

A while ago, [HighlyIrregular proposed a wording change](https://sustainability.meta.stackexchange.com/a/194/48) to:

> Sustainable Living Stack Exchange is all about working towards a way of living that enables humanity to live in equilibrium with the earth for the long term. This covers a wide range of subjects such as renewable energy, resource extraction, recycling, efficiency techniques and more.