# Update to the help center's "What topics can I ask about here?"

Tags: discussion

Take a look at the current text of the help center page, [What topics can I ask about here?](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). There are a few different issues with this page as it stands:

#### Description

The site description ("SL.SE is for folks dedicated to...") doesn't match what's on the [tour](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/tour), which was previously [edited and chosen on meta](https://sustainability.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/260/update-the-site-description).

#### List of related sites

The list of sites where questions might fit better could use re-thinking. [Historically](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/tools/posts/migrated/away), five questions have been migrated to Gardening. No other site has had more than one question migrated. These are the other destinations (one question each):

- Home Improvement
- The Great Outdoors
- Skeptics
- Earth Science
- Worldbuilding
- Biology
- Electrical Engineering
- Motor Vehicles

Neither Personal Finance nor Physics have ever been a destination, despite being on the help page. I believe we should adjust the list, and expand the description a bit for each to address the possible overlap.

For instance, I have seen a fair number of questions about specific solar PV setups that might have done better over on Electrical Engineering SE.

#### Area 51 recommendation

At the bottom of the page there is this text:

> If no site currently exists that will accept your question, you may commit to or propose a new site at Area 51, the place where new Stack Exchange communities are democratically created.

However, given the latest guidance from SE staff, an Area 51 proposal should [only be submitted by an existing community in need of a Q&A site](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27938/changes-to-the-area-51-process-v3-0). I think we should consider removing this line from our help page.

Comment: Worldbuilding seems like an odd one to include. Do we expect that one to come up often enough to warrant being on the list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thought I'd take a crack at re-writing this page in it's entirety. I've made the description more closely match what is on the tour (not 1:1 but closely aligned), given relevant topic examples (from our [tag map](https://sustainability.meta.stackexchange.com/q/352/8232)), removed the sentence about Area 51, and expanded the list of related sites based on the list in the question above. How does this sound?

> ### What topics can I ask about here?
>
> Sustainable Living Stack Exchange is for people passionate about living lives in a sustainable manner - a lifestyle that can be maintained indefinitely without depleting available resources. Whether you are an individual or business looking to make everyday changes, or an industry professional in waste recovery, renewable energy or clean technologies, chances are you're in the right place to ask your question!
>
> With your help, we're working together to build a library of detailed answers to every question on sustainability issues, including but not limited to:
>
> - Carbon footprints and environmental impacts
> - Electricity generation and storage
> - Product and appliance life-cycles, waste streams and waste minimisation
> - Reducing, Reusing, Recycling and alternatives
> - Global Warming & Climate Change
> - Ecosystems, Hydroponics and Permaculture
> - Construction materials and energy-efficient design
> - ...and any other questions regarding sustainable practices and designs!
>
> Please look around to see if your question has been asked before. It’s
> also OK to share knowledge by [asking and answering your own question](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/helpcenter/self-answer).
>
> If your question is not specifically related to Sustainability, it may be on topic for another Stack Exchange site:
>
> - [Gardening](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/) - for general gardening, weeding, planting and landscaping
> - [Home Improvement](https://diy.stackexchange.com/) - for D.I.Y. jobs on households including utilities or major appliances.
> - [The Great Outdoors](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/) - for exploration of nature and wilderness areas, including required skills and equipment.
> - [Skeptics](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/) - for challenging pseudoscience, biased data or disinformation. Note that a claim [must be notable](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) to be accepted on Skeptics.
> - [Earth Science](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/) - for scientific-based questions on climatology, geology, oceanography and [other earth science disciplines](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)
> - [Biology](https://biology.stackexchange.com/) - for biological concepts and mechanisms behind biological processes
> - [Electrical Engineering](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/) - questions about electronics, physical computing, microcontrollers, and embedded systems
> - [Motor Vehicle Maintennance & Repair](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/) - for questions on vehicles, combustion engines and EVs
>
> For more help, see [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask), and if you're still not sure, please [ask us on Meta](https://sustainability.meta.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Nice, I like it!

Comment: Overall, looks good to me. Just two small changes -- I think I'd take Skeptics off the list (I don't really think there's significant overlap there), and I'd add solar power systems to the list for electrical engineering.

Comment: Another thought... perhaps at the bottom we could add something like: "If you're unsure, ask on meta."

Comment: @LShaver - both good points. I've added a link to meta at the bottom. As for Skeptics, yeah, it's probably not the most relevant, although there is a lot of climate change disinformation out there - it could help to have it as a place for people to go to debunk that stuff. It's up to you though :-)

Comment: Nice. I'll leave it up for a while to see if there's additional feedback, then implement.

Comment: Looks good to me. I just [enacted this change](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Thanks for putting this together!

Comment: @Nic you beat me to it! :)