# Site maintenance: Focus on quality

Tags: discussion

I would like to point to [this Meta announcement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257614/graduation-site-closure-and-a-clearer-outlook-on-the-health-of-se-sites?cb=1), which concerns graduation (i.e. loss of "beta" status) and site closures across the Stack Exchange network.

For some time (about 830 days to be precise) I have been worried about [our Area 51 stats](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/33364/sustainable-living), which have been very low on questions. (Our public stats are being recorded [here](https://sustainability.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56/site-statistics) by [THelper ♦](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/users/99/thelper) & [EnergyNumbers ♦](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/users/48/energynumbers).)

According to the announcement, sites will not be closed down as long as they are properly maintained. Effectively, we may direct all our focus on quality control and not worry too much about churning out too many questions.

So I encourage everyone to **edit, flag, comment on** existing questions and answers and visit the [review queue](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/review). I don't think this site will take off any time soon, but our site views (at the moment a stable 800-1000 visits per day, growing steadily) are nothing to be ashamed of, so let's just try to give these daily 800-1000 passers-by the best site experience we can give them by increasing the quality of our questions & answers. It's reassuring to know that our efforts will not be deleted.

Comment: I fully agree, except for "_I don't think this site will take off any time soon_". Personally, I think we took off quite a while ago. Sustainability SE may not be a big site, but we do fulfill a need. It doesn't matter if we have a 'beta' label, that's just a name. It's what we do that counts!

Comment: @THelper By "take off" I meant getting 10 questions per day and graduating. I agree that we're a nice small site with some great questions & answers and it's nice to know that we won't be shut down any time soon. I also think that sustainability is not a dying art, but an emerging one, so I expect the activity to increase over time.